How to Upload a Video from a CDN URL as a Facebook Reel via API Without Downloading Locally?
I'm working on a Python script that uploads videos directly to a Facebook Page as Reels using the Facebook Graph API. My videos are hosted on a CDN, and I would like to upload them directly to Facebook without downloading them to my local server.
I am currently using Facebook's video_reels endpoint to upload videos as reels. For local files, the process works perfectly by uploading the video in binary form. However, I want to avoid downloading the video locally when it's hosted on a CDN and instead directly upload it from the CDN URL.
Here’s a simplified version of my current code:
import requests

# Facebook API parameters
page_access_token = 'your_page_access_token'
page_id = 'your_page_id'
api_version = 'v20.0'
video_url = 'https://cdn.example.com/video.mp4'  # CDN URL of the video
video_description = "My awesome reel"
video_title = "Reel Title"
thumbnail_path = 'thumb.jpg'


# Step 1: Initialize the upload session for reels
def initialize_upload_reel():
    url = f"https://graph.facebook.com/{api_version}/{page_id}/video_reels"
    payload = {
        'upload_phase': 'start',
        'access_token': page_access_token
    }
    
    response = requests.post(url, data=payload)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.json()
        video_id = data['video_id']
        print(f"Upload session started. Video ID: {video_id}")
        return video_id
    else:
        raise Exception(f"Error initializing reel upload: {response.text}")

# Step 2: Upload the reel video file
def process_upload_reel(video_id, file_size):
    url = f"https://rupload.facebook.com/video-upload/v20.0/{video_id}"

    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'OAuth {page_access_token}',
        'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
        'offset': '0',
        'file_size': str(file_size)
    }

    with open(video_url, 'rb') as file_data:
        response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=file_data)
    
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print("Reel Uploaded")
    else:
        raise Exception(f"Error uploading reel video: {response.text}")

def publish_reel(video_id, description, publish_time=None, published=True):
    url = f"https://graph.facebook.com/{api_version}/{page_id}/video_reels"
    thumb_file = {'thumb': open(thumbnail_url, 'rb')}
    
    payload = {
        'access_token': page_access_token,
        'video_id': video_id,
        'upload_phase': 'finish',
        'title': title_entry.get(),  # Ensure title is passed
        'description': description_entry.get()  # Ensure description is passed
    }

    if publish_time:
        payload['video_state'] = 'SCHEDULED'
        payload['scheduled_publish_time'] = publish_time
    else:
        payload['video_state'] = 'PUBLISHED' if published else 'DRAFT'

    response = requests.post(url, data=payload, files=thumb_file)
    thumb_file['thumb'].close()

    if response.status_code == 200:
        check_video_status(video_id)
        
    else:
        raise Exception(f"Error publishing reel: {response.text}")


The Problem:
When I attempt to upload using the CDN URL, I receive the following error message:
{
  "error": {
    "message": "There was a problem uploading your video file. Please try again with another file.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 6000,
    "error_subcode": 1363130,
    "error_user_title": "Video Upload Is Missing",
    "error_user_msg": "The video was not uploaded.",
    "fbtrace_id": "Ai3SicB2QxOVA-ZpIQu7cjT"
  }
}

It seems like Facebook's Reels API doesn't support uploading videos directly from a CDN URL using the file_url parameter, or I may be missing something in the implementation.
Question:
Is it possible to upload videos directly from a CDN URL to Facebook Reels via the Graph API without downloading the video locally first?
If yes, how should I structure my API request to achieve this?
If no, what is the recommended approach for handling CDN-hosted videos in this scenario (such as avoiding downloading the video to the server)?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Are you sure you're using the correct endpoint? On this page, the only endpoint that uses the file_url parameter is https://rupload.facebook.com/video-upload/v20.0/[video_id].

@EricFrancis12 It is happening in three stage, I will update the question.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/video-api/guides/reels-publishing/#upload-a-hosted-file suggests upload from a URL is possible, the file_url needs to be passed as a request header according to their example there though.

@C3roe currently Facebook Reel Upload using its Reels Publishing API does not work, if the reel is to be scheduled or saved as drafts.
